# MilestoneUtils - writing test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, casemilestone

I was working off of the code provided here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5

The test class they provided did not cover the full class. Still being a little new to writing test classes, how could I make sure I get the full coverage? Currently I at 57% with the if statement claiming to not be covered.

```
/*
Class provided by Salesforce help document
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5
*/
public class MilestoneUtils {
    public static void completeMilestone_case(List<Id> caseIds, String milestoneName, DateTime complDate) { 
        
        System.debug('calling MilestoneUtils with these inputs: MilestoneName='
                                 +milestoneName+' completeDate='+complDate);
        System.debug('Case list with milestones to complete: '+JSON.serializePretty(caseIds));
        
        List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
                from CaseMilestone cm
                where caseId in :caseIds and cm.MilestoneType.Name=:milestoneName 
                and completionDate = null limit 1];
        if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
            for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
                cm.completionDate = complDate;
            }
            update cmsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class I attempted to write (see link for what salesforce had)

```
/*
Test Class provided by Salesforce help document
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5
Modified to meet validation rule requirements
*/

@isTest
private class MilestoneUtils_Test {

    static testMethod void TestCompleteMilestone_Case(){
        // create data needed to test
        // Entitlement is hooked up to account in the background, even when set for case        
        List<Account> acts = new List<Account>();
        Account myAcc = new Account(Name='TestAct', phone='1001231234');
        acts.add(myAcc);

        Account busAcc = new Account(Name = 'TestForMS', phone='4567890999');
        acts.add(busAcc);
        insert acts;
        Contact cont = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'LastName', phone='4567890999', accountid = busAcc.id);
        insert(cont);

        Id contactId = cont.Id;

        Entitlement entl = new Entitlement(Name='TestEntitlement', AccountId=busAcc.Id);
        insert entl;

        String entlId;
        if (entl != null)
            entlId = entl.Id; 

        String milestoneName = 'Test Milestone';
        
        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
        if (entlId != null){
            Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case 1 with Entitlement ', 
                EntitlementId = entlId, ContactId = contactId, Origin = 'Direct Entry');
            cases.add(c);
            c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case 2 with Entitlement ', 
                EntitlementId = entlId, ContactId = contactId, Origin = 'Direct Entry');
            cases.add(c);
        }
        

        if (cases.isEmpty()==false){
            insert cases;
            List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
            for (Case cL : cases){
                caseIds.add(cL.Id);
            }
            milestoneUtils.completeMilestone_case(caseIds, milestoneName, System.now());
            //check database that completed data has been filled in for this milestone
            /*
            List<CaseMilestone> milestone_results = [Select Id, CaseId, CompletionDate, MilestoneType.Name 
                                                     from CaseMilestone cm 
                                                     where cm.caseId in :caseIds 
                                                     ];
            system.assertEquals(caseIds.size(), milestone_results.size());
            */
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Any direction is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your code coverage by taking out the unnecessary if statement:

```
/*
Class provided by Salesforce help document
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5
*/
public class MilestoneUtils {
    public static void completeMilestone_case(List<Id> caseIds, String milestoneName, DateTime complDate) { 
        List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
                from CaseMilestone cm
                where caseId in :caseIds and cm.MilestoneType.Name=:milestoneName 
                and completionDate = null limit 1];
        for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
            cm.completionDate = complDate;
        }
        update cmsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Further, your unit test code doesn't need to check if the lists are empty, either; they should definitely not be, considering that you're creating your data correctly. You should write your test as if it knows what it's doing, because it is completely in control of its environment.

In addition, you need to make sure that you're actually creating milestones. Check your Setup configuration to make sure that you're actually creating milestones.

Comment: After removing the if statement (which again this class came from salesforce) I still am missing converage on this line inside the for loop: "cm.completionDate = complDate;". I am trying to get 100% coverage. Is there anything I can do to get that line covered?